# Basis for order topology

Tags: general-topology

If $X= \{-5\} \cup(0,1) \cup[4,8)$, what is the basis for the order topology on $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ has a minimum $-5$ so all sets of the form $[-5,a)_X=\{x \in X\mid -5 \le x < a\}, a \in X$ are in the base, as well as all intervals $(a,b)_X=\{x \in X\mid a < x < b\}$ with $a,b \in X$.

Check that $\frac1n \to -5$ in the order topology and $1-\frac1n \to 4$ as well, which seems unintuitive. But realise that $X$ is order-isomorphic to $[0,1)$....

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @Muselive mine is correct and yours had a self-contradiction.

Comment: It had a minor typo, which you could have easily corrected with a comment, or just edited yourself.